# How can I access a database from a web page in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I've read and gone through a number of supposed instructions online but none of them are able to help me with my problem.

I'm trying to create a web project that can read from a database and display the values in a table, but every time I try to follow the instructions I find online, I just get errors. This is what my project currently looks like:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/mbNJYNK.png]

And when I run it I get this error:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GxlqcdU.png]

The database I'm referencing exists in the Server Explorer and has the EMPLOYEE table added. I've tried manually adding the `connectionString` to the `web.config` with the line:

```
<add name="kroger-webpage" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\kroger-webpage.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

but then I just get the error that the database is corrupted (I'm almost positive it's not.)

I've been trying to get this to work for hours; can someone here help?

Comment: Create a static method in that method write code that can be accessible on view.

Comment: Can you expand on how a method like that would be implemented here?

Comment: Try this Connection String     <add name="kroger-webpage"
           connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|kroger-webpage.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I was eventually able to get this working by altering the Connection String

```
<add name="kroger-webpage" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\[me]\source\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\kroger-webpage.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```